# Preserve time but convert to another timezone

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone, momentjs

I'm developing an app that lets users create dates/events in other timezones so I need to convert something like

2014-12-01T19:00:00.000Z to any particular timezone such as 'America/Phoenix'.

I'm using moment to handle it:

```
moment.tz(dt, 'America/New_York').format();
```

This outputs: 2014-12-01T14:00:00-05:00 which isn't what I want.

All I want to do is change the timezone not the time such that it would become 2014-12-01T19:00:00-05:00

Perhaps I could add the offset of 5 (depending on zone) before i convert the timezone so it would remain the same time? Maybe there is a better way?

Thanks, James

Answer (score 1):

You should recognize that the `Z` in your string means that the timestamp should be interpreted as UTC.  So if you change that to a different offset without adjusting the time accordingly, you are actually picking a *different* moment in time.  Usually, that's not the right thing to do.

By adjusting the time to match the offset for the time zone, Moment is doing the right thing.  It's interpreting the input string as UTC, and then adjusting it to the time zone provided.

It sounds like you would like to *ignore* the `Z` and treat the time as if it were *already* in a particular time zone.  The best place to change that would be wherever the string is originally generated.  If it's not in UTC, it shouldn't be putting the `Z` at the end in the first place.

However, you could certainly strip it off in JavaScript and get the result you're asking for.

```
var s = "2014-12-01T19:00:00.000Z";

moment.tz(s.replace(/Z$/,''), 'America/New_York').format();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use moment methods like:

- [startOf](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/)
- [hour](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/hour/)
- [minute](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/minute/)
- [get](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/get/)

Example:

```
moment.tz(dt, 'America/New_York').startOf('day').hour(dt.get('hour')).minute(dt.get('minutes')).format()
```

This will print the same hour and minute as the dt variable.

Hope it helps

Comment: Sure, but it will have a loss of precision, and it could actually end up on a different calendar date.